# javascript:get strings between specific strings

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I hava a long string like this `detail?ww=hello"....detail?ww=that"`.I want't to get all strings between `detail?ww=` and the next `"`,I use `.match(/detail\?ww=.+\"/g)` but the array i get contains `detail?ww=` and `"`,how can I only get strings without `detail?ww=` and `"`

Comment: Can you have a string like `detail?ww=hello=1;`?

Comment: Updated : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20621572/1636522.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JavaScript understood lookbehind, you could use that to match strings preceded by `detail?ww=` and followed by `;`. Unfotunately that is not the case, so a little more processing is required:

```
var str = 'detail?ww=hello"....detail?ww=that"';

var regexG = /detail\?ww\=(.+?)\"/g;
var regex  = /detail\?ww\=(.+?)\"/;
var matches = str.match(regexG).map(function(item){ return item.match(regex)[1] });

console.log(matches);
```

Some changes to your regexp:

`+?` - non-greedy quantifier.

Comment: oh thank you,i get it.I don't know the method `map` of javascript Array, now i get it.Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't really need the map method. You can simply iterate over the array of matches and build the new array you are interested in. I just find it much cleaner and easier to understand than straight iteration.

Comment: Before I tried to iterate over the array,but i think it's tedious, i just want a more cleaner method

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a basic loop :

```
var result = [],
    s = 'detail?ww=hello"....detail?ww=that"',
    r = /detail\?ww=([^"]+)/g,
    m;
while (m = r.exec(s)) {
    result.push(m[1]);
}
result; // ["hello", "that"]
```

```
[^"]+ : any char except double quotes, one or more times
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

---

Keep in mind that `map` is not supported by IE8 and below : http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.map. If you really don't like loops but need a cross browser compatible solution, here is an alternative :

```
var s = 'detail?ww=hello"....detail?ww=that"';
s = s.replace(/.*?detail\?ww=([^"]+")/g, '$1').match(/[^"]+/g) || [];
s; // ["hello", "that"]
```